# Open Graph and Facebook Like Total Fans Confusion

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

After implementing the Open Graph protocol and like button on my website, it says that there is one more fan besides me, but the admin page shows only myself as the fan.

Answer (score 0):

OG likes will also increase due to shares.  More details here under "What makes up the number shown on my Like button?"

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/